# Determining Locations of Circles to Optimally Cover a Polygon

Tags: geometry, circles, packing-problem

I want to completely cover a region on a map(Continental US)/polygon with circles of a certain radius. Is there a way to determine the best locations and how many circles would be needed to completely cover the polygon? A certain threshold of overlap would be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Some recent work uses the phrase  "connected sensor cover" for this problem,
and you can find literature by searching for that phrase, e.g.,

> S. Funke, A. Kesselman, F. Kuhn, Z. Lotker, and M. Segal. "Improved approximation
>   algorithms for connected sensor cover." *Wirel. Netw.*, 13(2):153–164, Apr.
>   2007. ([Springer link](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-540-28634-9_5).)

There is a long history of related work. Here is one paper from the math literature:

> R. Kershner. "The number of circles covering a set." *American Journal of Mathematics*,
>   pages 665–671, 2010.
>   ([Jstor link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2371320).)